# If using sockets to pass sensitive data between two scripts in the same Tkinter app, over localhost, are there any security concerns?

Tags: python, sockets, security, tcp, python-sockets

I am implementing a `socket` in Python to pass data back and forth between two scripts running on the same machine as part of a single Tkinter application.

This data, in many cases, will be highly sensitive (i.e. personal credit card numbers).

**Does passing the data between scripts in this way open me up to any security concerns?**

Server side:

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print buf
        break
```

Client side:

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))
clientsocket.send('hello')
```

[Code source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297623/1318135)

Additional considerations:

- This will only ever function as part of a single Tkinter application, on a single machine. Localhost will always be specified.
- I am unable to use `multiprocessing` or `threading`; please no suggestions for using one of those or an alternative, other than varieties of `socket`. For more info as to why, see this [SO question, answers, and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797770/tkinter-application-freezes-while-continually-polling-pipe-for-contents-multi/46802154?noredirect=1#comment80748400_46802154). It has to do with this needing to function on Windows 7 and *nix, as well as my desired set-up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287306/sending-encrypted-strings-using-socket-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Yes, passing the data between scripts in this way may raise a security concerns. If the attacker has an access to the same machine - he can easily sniff the traffic using the tool like tcpdump for example.

To avoid this you should encrypted your traffic - I have posted a comment below your question with an example solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful to know! To clarify, does this risk exceed whatever risk would come from `multiprocessing.Pipe` for the same purpose? Does it exceed the risk of using Jupyter notebook (which deploys through localhost)? Just trying to understand amount of risk a bit better.

Comment: I am not sure how Jupyter is exchanging data, you can check it via:
* netstats -tapdn  |grep jupyter -i
Later when you have number of the ports use:
* tcpdump -xxxxvvvv -i any 'port ZZZ' # where ZZZ is a port number